# Creating a new page width every row MySQL in mpdf

Tags: mysql, mpdf

I have a little problem width mpdf : 
I want to create a new page for every row of my table 
I don't know how to do.
Thank's for help.
Yves.
the code :

```
     $html = '';
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER by id ASC';
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL!'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());   
    while($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
    $texte = $data['texte'];
    $html .='<div class="texte_justify">'.$texte.'</div>';
    }
    include("../mpdf.php");
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output('pdf.pdf','I');
    exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so, you can use the AddPage() function to change the formatting of the next page.

```
include("../mpdf.php");

$html = '';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER by id ASC';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL!'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error());   

$mpdf=new mPDF();    
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($req)){
    $texte = $data['texte'];
    $html .='<div class="texte_justify">'.$texte.'</div>';
    $mpdf->AddPage('L','','','','',50,50,50,50,10,10);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
}


$mpdf->Output('pdf.pdf','I');
exit;
```